# Куки с префиксом www и без него разные. Как исправить?

Tags: python, django

Как вы справились с такой бедой: если кука создаётся у домена с префиксом `www`, то и сохраняется только у домена с префиксом (т.е. у сайта без префикса этой куки не сохранено). И аналогично у сайта без префикса `www`.
Как это решить без переадресаций, или всё же с переадресациями лучше?

Comment: Имхо самый простой вариант редирект на одну из версий. Так и для индексации если не ошибаюсь лучше. И местами о построении внутренних ссылок не надо задумываться.

Comment: @Kers А нельзя ли установить домены по умолчанию (для сохранения кук), чтобы и с префиксом, и без него?

Comment: @Kers например SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN решит эту проблему?

Comment: для объединения всех поддоменов точно да.. а под www и без сходу затрудняюсь сказать. Попробуйте так `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.MY_SITE.RU'` (с точкой в начале)

Comment: @Kers ура. Всё работает. Благодарю

Answer (score 1):

Решение от @Kers

`SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.MY_SITE.RU'` (с точкой в начале)